# Using Nginx with Asterisk ARI

Tags: asterisk

I would appreciate if somebody could tell me whether Asterisk's default web server can be replaced by nginx, I am planning to delve into ARI and need to know the possibilities of using nginx with asterisk for production environment.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ARI have almost no relation to asterisk

It use php.

So if you can do php cgi on nginx - you can try go with it.

I never tried that, becuase it have no real sence. You also can try rewrite all that to fastcgi.